# Could not find ColorSync function message in xcode message

Tags: iphone

I have updated my `xcode` to 4.2 beta version. The image picked from the image picker is not shown in the imageView. It creates the following message in the console:

```
ImageIO - could not find ColorSync function 'ColorSyncProfileCreateWithName'
ImageIO - could not find ColorSync function 'ColorSyncProfileCopyData'
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing a older version of xcode. Make sure to uninstall properly. Because iOS 5.0 is still under NDA so there likely to be some changes in some API's.